# Schema Designer is Not Showing up

Tags: xml, solr

The Schema Designer Option is not available when Apache Solr 8.11 is installed. Below shows the options it provides.
[image]

However it's available in the official documentation page as below.  Im new to configuring Apache Solr. What im missing here?
Need to create a Schema.XML file for the 8.11 version.

[image]

Comment: what happens when you click on new Schema?

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/schema-designer.html

Comment: The difference between your screenshot and the one from the reference manual is that the reference manual is running in cloud mode while you're running in standalone mode. That might be relevant, although it isn't mentioned in the guide.

Comment: There is no new schema option available. it provide only to create a new core. for the core we need to have a schema.xml created.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, the schema disgner is only available in cloud, as stated in the docs here:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/solr-admin-ui.html#schema-designer
[image]